# What should I call this tab icon within task timeline?

Tags: task-list

[image: task timeline]

What should I call this tab graphic for the Display as Callout and Display as Bar fuction within the Task Timeline?

I'm writing a tutorial and I want to make sure I have the terminology correct. Ironic, I know. lol :)

Answer (score 3):

The term for the shape itself is brace/bracket. In context of a callout, you would probably call it a selector. Personally though, I would just refer to the whole thing as a Callout and identify the bracket as "the range."